# get row number of record in resultset sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table full of documents with serial numbers - columns:

- docid int
- writing text
- submissionDate datetime

...and I'd like to find out where a particular serial number lies in a query against the table.

For example, if I ordered the resultset by submissionDate asc, I might want to know where document 34 is within that ordering (i.e. is it in position 11?)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the row number even if that's not one of the rows being returned. You can use a CTE for that:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        docid,
        writing,
        submissionDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY submissionDate) AS position
    FROM
        My_Table
)
SELECT
    docid,
    writing,
    submissionDate,
    position
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    docid = 34
```

This also requires SQL Server 2005 or greater of course.

Answer (score 5):

### SQL Server 2005+, using analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.docid,
       t.writing,
       t.submissiondate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.submissiondate) AS position
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

### Non-analytic version

This approach risks non-sequential values because if there are two (or more) records with the same `submissiondate` value -- they all will have the same position value.  It's on par with using RANK or DENSE_RANK analytic functions, because ROW_NUMBER will always grant a unique value for every record without regard for duplicate values.

```
SELECT x.docid,
       x.writing,
       x.submissiondate,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM YOUR_TABLE y
         WHERE y.submissiondate <= x.submissiondate) AS position
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Window Function `rank()`.

Example ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)):

```
SELECT i.ProductID, p.Name, i.LocationID, i.Quantity
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY i.Quantity DESC) AS 'RANK'
  FROM Production.ProductInventory i 
 INNER JOIN Production.Product p  ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID
 ORDER BY p.Name;
```

It's  very powerful.

It SQL standard and it should work in SQL Server 2005 and newer versions.

Comment: @Caveatrob: Update your question showing us your query and we'll help you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I plug in an ID value directly (rank and over is 1, of course). I tried creating a temp table with the rank as a field, and then querying the temp using the ID, but i'm not sure the temp table will have the proper order when it's created. Is that something I can count on?

Comment: @Caveatrob: I agree with Pablo - what you're saying makes no sense to us, you need to provide detail for us to be of any help to you.