# select next row of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL SERVER 2008. I have the following query:

```
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY ru.rul_icontfk 
           ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype, 
         ru.rul_ntiermax) AS order1, 
       ru.rul_ipk, 
       ru.rul_icontfk, 
       ru.rul_crultype, 
       ru.rul_cisbn, 
       ru.rul_crecipid, 
       ru.rul_ccalcmeth, 
       ru.rul_ctiertype, 
       ru.rul_ntiermax 
FROM   rules.ru 
       INNER JOIN ruletype rut 
               ON rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype 
       INNER JOIN country cnt 
               ON cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
WHERE  ru.rul_icontfk = '108122' --and rul_ipk=1227754 
ORDER  BY order1
```

```
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| order1 | rul_ipk | rul_icontfk | rul_crultype |   rul_cisbn   | rul_crecipid | rul_ccalcmeth | rul_ctiertype | rul_ntiermax  |
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | 1227752 |      108122 | 1            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |      9999999  |
|      2 | 1227758 |      108122 | 1            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |      9999999  |
|      3 | 1227754 |      108122 | 1            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      4 | 1227759 |      108122 | 2            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      5 | 1227755 |      108122 | 2            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      6 | 1227753 |      108122 | 3            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      7 | 1227760 |      108122 | 3            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      8 | 1227756 |      108122 | 3            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|      9 | 1227761 |      108122 | S            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|     10 | 1227762 |      108122 | T            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
|     11 | 1227757 |      108122 | 4            | 9780415910866 | S565154      | N             | LU            |       9999999 |
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I would like to know how to get the  records with  rul_ipk > 1227754, which they have the order1 > 3

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, 
                 rut.rut_crultype, 
                 RU.rul_ntiermax) AS row 
        FROM   rules ru 
               INNER JOIN ruletype rut 
                       ON rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype 
               INNER JOIN country cnt 
                       ON cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
        WHERE  ru.rul_icontfk = '108122') a 
WHERE  row > 3
```

```
+---------+-------------+
| rul_ipk | rul_icontfk |
+---------+-------------+
| 1227759 |      108122 |
| 1227755 |      108122 |
| 1227753 |      108122 |
| 1227760 |      108122 |
| 1227756 |      108122 |
| 1227761 |      108122 |
| 1227762 |      108122 |
| 1227757 |      108122 |
+---------+-------------+
```

I tried to get the results with this query to get the record number but I get the order1 = 1

```
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY ru.rul_icontfk 
           ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype, 
         RU.rul_ntiermax) AS order1, 
       RU.rul_ipk, 
       RU.rul_icontfk, 
       RU.rul_crultype, 
       RU.rul_cisbn, 
       RU.rul_crecipid, 
       RU.rul_ccalcmeth, 
       RU.rul_ctiertype, 
       RU.rul_ntiermax 
FROM   rules ru 
       INNER JOIN ruletype rut 
               ON rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype 
       INNER JOIN country cnt 
               ON cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
WHERE  ru.rul_icontfk = '108122' 
       AND rul_ipk = 1227754 
ORDER  BY order1
```

```
order1  rul_ipk rul_icontfk rul_crultype
1   1227754 108122  1


I tried this query

SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype, RU.rul_ntiermax) as row
   FROM RULES ru  
                    inner join ruletype rut on rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype                               
                    inner join country cnt on cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
                    WHERE ru.rul_icontfk  = '108122'
 ) a WHERE row >  (SELECT  rownum.order1  from (select row_number()  over (partition by ru.rul_icontfk order by rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype,
                    RU.rul_ntiermax) as order1,
                    RU.rul_ipk, RU.rul_icontfk, RU.rul_crultype, RU.rul_cisbn, 
                    RU.rul_crecipid, RU.rul_ccalcmeth, RU.rul_ctiertype, RU.rul_ntiermax 
                    from RULES ru  
                    inner join ruletype rut on rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype                               
                    inner join country cnt on cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
                    WHERE ru.rul_icontfk = '108122'  
                    ) as rownum  where rul_ipk=1227754)

which it give me the result desired but I don't know if there is a easiest way to do this

rul_ipk rul_icontfk rul_crultype
1227759 108122  2
1227755 108122  2
1227753 108122  3
1227760 108122  3
1227756 108122  3
1227761 108122  S
1227762 108122  T
1227757 108122  4
```

Comment: Are you trying to get record just order1 = 4?  You question is kind of confusing the way it is written.

Comment: Super duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090911/get-row-number-of-record-in-resultset-sql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645746/sql-server-row-number-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
The results of the columns row and order1 are 1. 

I modified the query to get the results desired


WITH  CTE AS 
(SELECT
       Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, 
             rut.rut_crultype, 
             RU.rul_ntiermax) AS row,
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY ru.rul_icontfk 
           ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype, 
         ru.rul_ntiermax) AS order1, 
       ru.rul_ipk, 
       ru.rul_icontfk, 
       ru.rul_crultype, 
       ru.rul_cisbn, 
       ru.rul_crecipid, 
       ru.rul_ccalcmeth, 
       ru.rul_ctiertype, 
       ru.rul_ntiermax 
FROM   rules ru 
       INNER JOIN ruletype rut 
               ON rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype 
       INNER JOIN country cnt 
               ON cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
WHERE  ru.rul_icontfk =108122 )
Select * from Cte where row > (Select row from cte where rul_ipk = 1227754 )

row order1  rul_ipk rul_icontfk
4   4   1227759 108122
5   5   1227755 108122
6   6   1227753 108122
7   7   1227760 108122
8   8   1227756 108122
9   9   1227761 108122
10  10  1227762 108122
11  11  1227757 108122


----> These are the results for each condition:
Select row from cte where rul_ipk = 1227754 
row
3

Select * from Cte 

row order1  rul_ipk rul_icontfk
1   1   1227752 108122
2   2   1227758 108122
3   3   1227754 108122
4   4   1227759 108122
5   5   1227755 108122
6   6   1227753 108122
7   7   1227760 108122
8   8   1227756 108122
9   9   1227761 108122
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a select with both row numbers and then using a CTE compare the two numbers in a where

```
WITH  CTE AS 
(SELECT
       Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, 
             rut.rut_crultype, 
             RU.rul_ntiermax) AS row,
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY ru.rul_icontfk 
           ORDER BY rut.rut_isortorder, cnt.ctr_caltcode3, rut.rut_crultype, 
         ru.rul_ntiermax) AS order1, 
       ru.rul_ipk, 
       ru.rul_icontfk, 
       ru.rul_crultype, 
       ru.rul_cisbn, 
       ru.rul_crecipid, 
       ru.rul_ccalcmeth, 
       ru.rul_ctiertype, 
       ru.rul_ntiermax 
FROM   rules.ru 
       INNER JOIN ruletype rut 
               ON rut.rut_crultype = ru.rul_crultype 
       INNER JOIN country cnt 
               ON cnt.ctr_cisocode = ru.rul_cctry 
WHERE  ru.rul_icontfk = '108122' --and rul_ipk=1227754 
ORDER  BY order1  )

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE order1 > row
```

Comment: Yes, I like that one but in that case I don't know the row_number() = 3. I have to do the query to know what row_number is the record with  ru.rul_icontfk = '108122' and rul_ipk=1227754 like my last query.